# Any info how Lombardi's Blueprint is built needed

Tags: gwt

I've found [Lombardi's Blueprint](http://blueprint.lombardi.com) as an example of applying GWT. It's awesome. 
I wonder how is it built, inspite of using GWT. What kind of widget and client JS frameworks did they use. Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A video on InfoQ, I haven't watched it, so it may or may not cover the topics your interested in:

- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Alex-Moffat-GWT-Blueprint

Answer (score 2):

Lombardi are rather open about their experiences with GWT - they have a very good [blog](http://development.lombardi.com/) about it. They also gave a [presentation](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/EffectiveGwt.html) on Google IO 2009 about it. Note however that some things are a bit out-of-date and, for example, could be done better/easier with GWT 2.0/2.1.